# Frequently Posted Comments

Tags: discussion, comments

On Code Review we often encounter questions with the same kind of problem over and over again.

Some of us are using the [auto comments script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) which allows you to maintain a list of comments to post.

What are some useful tin-can comments that can be good to have in your list of comments?

If you feel that a comment can be improved, you can post a comment on that specific answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is intended as a ready copy & paste version for including in the Auto-Comments script.

The Auto Comments script also has support for a "remote" feature where you can use this URL: `http://www.zomis.net/codereview/auto-comments`

```
###[Q] Broken Code
I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

###[Q] Question contains no code at all / a link to code
Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

###[Q] Answers Invalidated
Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

###[Q] Description is behind a link
Links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993)

###[A] Non-Review Answer
You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.

###[Q] Example Code
I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

###[Q] Bad Title
The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

###[Q] Question lacks description
This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

###[Q] Question containing code from someone else
Unfortunately, this is not code you own or maintain. [For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1294).

###[A] Answer which is a question
This isn't an answer to the question. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. If you are uncertain, take a look at [ask].

###[Q] Question contains code, but hidden behind a link
Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308). Code behind links is considered non-reviewable. Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

###[Q] Generic Best Practices
Generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please [**follow the tour**](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

###[Q] New user asking for code  
Unfortunately, we don't provide code, we review code you've written. Depending on your problem, another site of the [Stack Exchange network](//stackexchange.com/) can help you. Please see our [help/on-topic] for more information.

###[A] Good post by a new user :-)
Thanks for this great answer - I hope to see more from you in future!

###[Q] Good post by a new user :-)
Thanks for this great question - I hope you get some good reviews, and I hope to see more of your contributions here in future!
```

`[Q]` comments are available on questions, `[A]` comments on answers.

Comment: For those interested in having all of those in one easy copy-paste place, [see this other answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8507/42632).

Answer (score 19):

## Question contains non-working code.

> `Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.`

This comment makes our site scope much clearer, and is an invitation for the user to come back once the code works and get the full usage of Code Review.

Answer (score 16):

## OP has edited their question to include feedback received in answers, effectively invalidating existing answers.

Adapted from the famous meta post, "[For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/23788)":

> `I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers)*.`

The answer-invalidating edit should be rolled back, too.

If you don't have editing rights, you can use the comment below and flag for moderator attention.

> `Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. The site policy is explained in [What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers).`

Another version:

> `Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.`

Beginner friendly variant (after you rolled changes back):

> `While it's great that a review enabled you to improve your code, please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers. Doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review, as it unfortunately invalidates the existing review(s). This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question, so I rolled your changes back to the previous version. Please see see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)* for ways to announce your new code.`

Comment: I'd recommend changing the wording in the last one -- "goes against the Question and Answer style" is pretty vague and not very satisfying. "It invalidates the answers people have provided or are working on, which goes against [etc.]" would be better IMO, because it provides a clear reason that, honestly, stands up on its own.

Answer (score 14):

## Question contains Hypothetical Code / Pseudocode

> `I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)`

Answer (score 12):

## An answer contains a completely different solution with no explanation or justification.

> `You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.`

In addition, please flag the post as low quality.  Moderators may put an "insufficient explanation" notice on it, and we can [keep track of such posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/203683/post-notices-outstanding) for deletion in the future if no improvement is made.

Comment: Another version of this that I have used: `Although this answer provides an alternative way of implementing what the OP wants, commenting on what things you do differently, why you are doing it that way and pointing out the flaws in the OP's original code would make this a better answer. Copy-pasting code does not always provide a good learning experience.`

Comment: maybe we could also link [here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1990)

Comment: How to I flag as "low quality"? That's not an available option in the flagging dialog. Should I flag such an answer as "in need for moderator intervention"?

Comment: @MartinR Either "not an answer" or "in need of moderator intervention" would work.

Answer (score 11):

## Title is too generic

> `The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask] for examples.`

Another wording:

> `The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.`

Also feel free to edit the title and make it awesome. A good title can often become a hot question.

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5766/31562

Answer (score 9):

## I like all of these in one single place!

I put together and am actively maintaining a list of [easily usable copy-paste responses](https://github.com/Phrancis/Stack-Exchange-Utilities/blob/master/Code%20Review%20Copy-Paste.md) on Github, which everyone is free to use, copy and clone as they please. They are inspired by the responses found here.

I made that because I find it easier to keep it organized and up-to-date this way, rather than trying to maintain answers to this post. Feel welcome to help yourself to it.

*License is [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/).*

Answer (score 8):

## Code Challenge Missing Description

> `Links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993)`

Answer (score 7):

## Question contains little to no description about what the code does.

> `This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)`

Answer (score 7):

## Question contains no code at all

> `Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!`

## Question contains code, but hidden behind a link

> `Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Code behind links is considered non-reviewable. Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!`

Answer (score 7):

## Question asking for help understanding code

> `Unfortunately this question appears to be off topic because it is about understanding code. [The point of a code review is to identify things about the code that can be improved and discuss possible improvements](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/198).`

Answer (score 5):

## Answer which is asking for clarification

> `This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.`

Comment: Now that I think about it anyone can do the moderator version. I cannot transform answers into comments, but I can copy+paste the answer as a comment and copy+paste your second text as a comment to the answer. That way the community is perceived as helpful instead of an obstacle.

Comment: This looks like one of those that are built into the Stack Exchange review system.

Answer (score 4):

## Answer which is a question

> `This isn't an answer to the question. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you are uncertain, take a look at [ask].`

Comment: This is good, but seems really similar to this one. Can they be merged somehow? http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4955/41243

Comment: @RubberDuck, I think it should stay on its own. This is in the range of "Hey pretty good code, but I have a question about xyz".

Comment: When I started (on SO) I wanted clarifications to the question, but did not have enough rep to write a comment. So I had to write it in an answer, which is wrong. Then people commented I should write a comment instead, which I could not. I see it as a problem that people try doing the right thing, but are prevented by the system and then mocked by unobservant people (sadly, mostly moderators). Moderators should turn such answers into comments, but not everyone has mod rights, so take a second look at the answerer's rep before copy+pasting the above text and similar for a comment.

Comment: @nwp Did you read the header ? -> `Answer which is a question`

Comment: I did. "What do you mean by `foobar`?" is one of those answers which are questions. Clearly "Good code, but I have a question about xyz" is a different type of answer which is a question. I just want people to pay more attention when copy+pasting comments, because it really sucks when they get it wrong.

Comment: For the asking about clarification we have `This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).`

Comment: @nwp Added version about clarification http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4998/29371

Comment: Already handled by review.

Answer (score 4):

## New user asks for code

> `Unfortunately, we don't provide code, we review code you've written. Depending on your problem, another site of the [StackExchange network](//stackexchange.com) can help you. Please see our [help/on-topic] for more information.`

Answer (score 3):

## A Stack Overflow user recommends Code Review

### Off-topic question

#### Generic

> `Unfortunately, this question would be off-topic on Code Review, see [the migration guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/21002) or [the on-topic section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)`

#### New feature

> `Unfortunately, this question would be off-topic on Code Review, see [the migration guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/21002) or [the on-topic section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). OP asks how to implement a new feature, and not yet written code is off-topic on Code Review.`

#### Code not working

> `Unfortunately, this question would be off-topic on Code Review, see [the migration guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/21002) or [the on-topic section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). OP's code does not yet yield the desired behaviour, and code not working ass intended is off-topic on Code Review.`

#### Explanation of existing code

> `Unfortunately, this question would be off-topic on Code Review, see [the migration guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/21002) or [the on-topic section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). OP asks how the code works, however, third party code is strictly off-topic on Code Review.`

Answer (score 2):

#### Question asks for an explanation of code

> Unfortunately this question doesn't reflect what the site is about. We review code that you have written for improvements. It's not on topic to ask for explanations of code that has been written by someone other than you. For more information, see the [help/on-topic]. Thanks.

Comment: " that has been written by someone else than you" - so... if it's my own code that I wrote whilst drunk...?

Answer (score 2):

## Question can be improved - Guide for good questions

> `Your question currently leaves some things to be desired. I'd recommend taking a look at [Simon's Guide to posting a good question](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429). In particular, you could improve {todo}.`

Don't forget to fill in the `{todo}` part. Or scrap it completely.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list I use and update periodically - also [available on GH](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aelliott1485/aelliott1485.github.io/master/autocomments.cr.md).

```
###[Q] general title (about CR goals)
The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

### [Q] title about mechanism
Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews. Please see [_How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

###[Q] update title to summarize outcome
We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarizes the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

###[Q] off-topic: Authorship of code
Please [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), and read up at our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This question is _off-topic_ because this site is for reviewing code. [“_For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers. We expect you, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is._”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

###[Q] not working
Unfortunately this question is _off-topic_ because this site is for reviewing **working** code. Please [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up at our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). When the code works then feel free to [edit] the post to include it for a review.

###[Q] broken
Unfortunately this post is off-topic for this site. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - note that it states "_If you are looking for feedback on a specific **working** piece of code...then you are in the right place!_" When the code works as intended, please [edit] your post to include the working code and it can be reviewed."

###[Q] missing code context
Please provide more complete code - e.g. complete function/method/class. ["_there are significant pieces of the core functionality missing, and we need you to fill in the details. Excerpts of large projects are fine, but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works._"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/120114)

###[Q] need more details
It would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

###[Q] stub code
Unfortunately this question does not match what this site is about. Please re-read the Help center page [_What topics can I ask about here?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - specifically the third question. Reviewers need more than hypothetical/stub code. For more information, see [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/120114).

###[Q] untested
If you're not sure whether your code works correctly, I'm afraid it's not yet ready for review. Code Review is for finished code that you believe to be functionally correct.

###[Q] More than one question asked
It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

###[Q] Duplicate Closure
This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

###[Q] Common title
What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

###[Q] Edited Title
I [changed the title]() so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

###[Q] advice for future code
Questions asking for advice about [code not yet written](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3651/120114) are [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as the code is not ready for review.

###[Q] 3rd party code link
Maybe you missed the text on the right side when asking: "_Your question must contain code that is already working correctly, and **the relevant code sections must be embedded in the question**._" Questions must [include the code to be reviewed](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/120114). Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself.

###[Q] 3rd party code link
If you want more code than that snippet of HTML reviewed then please expand the code here. [Please embed the code to be reviewed directly in the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/120114). Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself. A [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) could also be used to embed the code.

###[Q] editor added code from 3rd party link
Thank you for attempting to help keep the question on-topic, but please refrain from adding the code to the post- [per licensing and other reasons](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/467/120114) the OP must be the one to do that.

###[Q] Commented with more details
When adding additional information you should [edit] your question  instead of adding a comment. I have added that information to your post. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Help Center page about Comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

###[Q] Add answer instead of comment
Please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and note that [short answers are acceptable](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1479/120114).

###[Q] merge accounts
it appears you have a registered account (as evidenced by the suggested edit), which can be merged with your unregistered account. You can use the [contact SE page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) and request the accounts be merged.

###[Q] rolled back(200_success's)
I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

###[Q] don't update code
Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

###[Q] code rolled back
I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code any more. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). See the section _What should I not do?_ on [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information

###[Q] rolled back last edit (Graipher's)
I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are [not allowed to change your code anymore](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

###[Q] SQL need more info
Please read the [sql tag wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/sql/info) - especially the **Question Guidelines** section. Before reviewing this code, it would be helpful to have some more information about the data.

###[Q] Need more context
This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the purpose of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. The title needs an [edit] to simply [state the task](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

###[Q] Which site and CR or not
See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

###[Q] database design with no code
[Code to generate such a database can be reviewed](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9116/120114) but without any code it seems it is not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

###[Q] UML design off-topic unless with code.
Ahoy! The general consensus is that [UML designs are not reviewable unless they accompany code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1926/120114).

###[Q] Character limit increased
If you are concerned about the size of your code, bear in mind that [the character limit on Code Review was increased to 65k](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7163/120114).

###[Q] cross-posted
Please note that [cross-posting is generally frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/341145) and should not be done.

###[Q] image of code/text
Please [add text instead of an image of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1575353).

###[Q] Should use English only
["_Unless you're posting on a language-related site (e.g. French Language) or a site where all questions are expected to be in a different language (e.g. Stack Overflow in Spanish), all posts are expected to be in English_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/341145).

###[A] ChatGPT answer
[AI generated answers are not welcome for various reasons, including plagiarism.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10863/120114)

###[A] Different language
Hi. The question is tagged [tag:Javascript]. The consensus is that [answers should use the same language as the code in the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2631/120114). Please write your answer according to the tags. Thanks! :)

###[A] Nothing insightful
This answer doesn't really offer much for the OP. Please (re-) read [The help center page _How do I write a good answer?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Note it states: "_Every answer must make at least one **insightful observation** about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"

###[A] don't answer off-topic questions
Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.

###[A] don't answer questions likely to be closed
[Please refrain from answering questions that are likely to get closed.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/35991)

###[A] don't answer questions likely to be closed - please flag until you gain CV priv
[Please refrain from answering questions that are likely to get closed.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/35991). In the future please use the  [flag option](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) until you gain the [cast close and reopen votes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege

###[A] link-only answer
A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

###[A] Doesn't answer question
This does not answer the question the OP posed (i.e. "_How can I make it run faster? How can I write it in a OOP paradigm, and will it run faster?_"). Please see [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) before posting an answer. If you have a related but separate question, you can [ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) another question and mention this question, or if you have code not working, try [SO].

###[A] alternative solution/ code dump
You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process. Please read [Why are alternative solutions not welcome?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8404/120114)

###[A] follow up question
This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), though only if you have **working code**. This statement would be appropriate as a  [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), though you will need to earn 50 reputation points first...

###[A] Answers just to say Thanks!
Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Code Review way of saying thank you.

###[A] Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)
Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

###[A] Requests to OP for further information
This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

###[A] OP using an answer for further information
Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

###[A] OP adding a new question as an answer
If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

###[A] Another user adding a 'Me too!'
If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

###[A] NAA self-answer on CR
While OPs are [encouraged to answer their own questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) bear in mind that ["_Your answer must meet the standards of a Code Review answer, just like any other answer. **Describe what you changed, and why**._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). [Code-only answers that don't actually review the code are insufficient](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463) and are subject to deletion.

###[A] post-accepted answer - Please consider voting
Thank you for taking the time to accept the answer. Please consider voting on it as well. ["_The first thing you should do after reading someone's answer to your question is vote on the answer, like any user with sufficient reputation does. Vote up answers that are helpful, and vote down answers that give poor advice._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

### [A] short answer- expand?
While it seems that [short answers are acceptable](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1479/120114) are you able to expand this answer, perhaps explaining reasons for the suggestion?

###[C] Too localized
This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

###[EQ] Improper tagging
The tags you were using are not appropriate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Welcome a good first-time poster

Let's be supportive when people get things right early on.  :-)

```
###[A] Good post by a new user :-)
Thanks for this great answer - I hope to see more from you in future!

###[Q] Good post by a new user :-)
Thanks for this great question - I hope you get some good reviews, and I hope to see more of your contributions here in future!
```

Comment: Perhaps add a note about when such comments should be removed. After a week?