# Is the "I downvoted because..." site something that is useful here?

Tags: discussion, third-party, down-votes

When we have a bad question, pasting one of the appropriate questions from [this site](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) may help, specifically [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) in a comment.

Comment: Related: [Frequently Posted Comments](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4952)

Comment: I downvoted because...

Comment: Why not just put the energy into fixing the problem? An image of code isn't just a problem for you, it's a problem for other potential reviewers. Downvoting doesn't change that. Downvoting for an image doesn't reflect the merit or non-merit of the code. Sure, it's excusable behavior. But again, it doesn't fix anything or make the site better.

Comment: It *could* become useful, yes... but currently it's too focused on Stack Overflow to be usable on CR IMO.

Answer (score 3):

That's neat, I have something similar [on my GitHub](https://github.com/Phrancis/Stack-Exchange-Utilities/blob/master/Code%20Review%20Copy-Paste.md) though it's meant for me, I like how this is designed to explain to a user how to improve their question. If you want to, I (and probably some other regulars) would be happy to help put something together that's more adapted to Code Review and prepare some pull requests to add to the website.

Comment: [on my own volition I started two CR pages and got them pulled in](https://github.com/WillSullivan/idownvotedbecause/pull/107) - feel free to expand, update, etc... maybe these would help with the scenario outlined in [simon's response to the CRCQR](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9004/120114)