# Announcement: New chat room CRCQR

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, chat

As some of the regulars at the SE Code Review site already noticed we have a new chat room to request and discuss question closures:

- [**SE Code Review Close Questions room**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85306/se-code-review-close-questions-room)

I've setup that room due to the increasing rate of close worthy questions here, and it seems to be better to have a defined protocol for close vote requests.
The already existing 2ndMonitor room doesn't do a good job about that IMO.

The protocol used is the same as used in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and also other rooms like [The Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

I want to invite everyone interested to participate at this chat room and help to keep the SE Code Review site cleaner, and close *off-topic* questions quicker and more efficiently.

Regarding the protocol and room policies you can currently refer to the [SOCVR FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq). We'll see if we need to setup our own in near future, since some things work different at SE Code Review.

Comment: Note: Duga was never meant to catch off-topic questions. Duga helps with invalid recommendations from SO to CR and answer invalidations. Not with off-topic questions.

Comment: I noticed that [SOCVR.org](https://socvr.org) (did you really have to buy a domain for that room?)  said *"The SO Close Vote Review Chat Room is a group of like-minded people who want to make a difference in the CV queue, reviewing and clean-up efforts."* - Do you want discussions, or do you want like-minded people?

Comment: @Simon I'd like to have like minded people, but I am open for discussion of course. I simply didn't find an appropriate tag for such kind of announcement here.

Comment: @SimonForsberg At the moment the room is a bit of all, it's still under consideration to create a meta room for the discussion.

Comment: @SimonForsberg It would be even nice if one of the ♦mods would like to apply a [tag:featured] tag on this announcement.

Comment: Shouldn't we wait with featuring till it has actually come of the ground? We're still gathering a minimum of momentum. Let's get it it rolling before asking for official support.

Comment: @Mast I was pretty astonished about the quick attention and the engagement of some particular regulars. Thus I decided to write up that announcement here. _@ThomasWard_ strayed in some doubts, but I still feel encouraged that this room will establish well.

Answer (score 2):

### The progress so far...

This room has been ongoing for a little more than two days now. In this time, there's been 24 requests to close and 1 request to reopen.

Some questions had comments that were just copy-paste of the close reason. I consider this not being helpful because of a few reasons:

- As an OP I would feel bad that someone just copy-pasted the official close reason and posted that as a comment.
- Once the question is closed, the comment is totally obsolete. If they would be flagged I would definitely remove them without question. **The idea of the comments is to be a separate explanation of the reasons behind the closure.**
- They are not focusing much on *how to fix* or *what is the next constructive step* for the OP to take.

The ideal comment is a comment that:

1. Starts friendly
2. Explains why the question is off-topic, preferably also with reasoning about why this is rule exists on the site
3. Ends constructive by focusing on what the OP can do to fix this. What is the next step for the OP to take to create positive content and become a good member of Code Review Stack Exchange?

---

Now let's take a look at some statistics:

Of these 24 questions that were mentioned as "close-vote please", there are:

- Questions that has a comment that is just a copy-pasted close reason: 9
- Questions with helpful comments by people from the chat room: 12. Extra credit to Thomas Ward for posting helpful comments.
- Questions with helpful comments from other people than the chat room: 5
- Questions with no comments at all: 2.
- Questions **from entirely new users** with no comments at all: 2. (Same 2 questions as above)
- Questions that actually are on-topic: 2
- Questions that are in a gray area: 2 (at least 2 that I consider being in the gray-zone)
- Questions with an old user saying "Damn, this place is hostile": 1

So far, I am not impressed.

I really don't want to see questions from new users being closed without a comment.

I would like to see more than 50% of the questions having constructive comments from people from the chat room.

I would like to see more constructive comments that are not just copy-pasting the close reasons.

I don't want this to be an angry mob of people that are just down-voting and closing things.

I do see another way to increase the quality of Code Review: Create more positive content. Vote on good things. Post good questions. Share good answers.

I am hoping that one day I will see a "SE Code Review Great Questions Room".

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing this compared to stats before we used the chat room. As "Questions that has a comment that is just a copy-pasted close reason" and "Questions with no comments at all" have been going on for ages.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yup, and a lot of them are mine. I've started leaving those around long, long ago.

Comment: "So far, I am not impressed." Ok, what would impress you? And do you have the manpower for it? Just posting good questions is not going to cut it and it won't solve the queues filling with increasing speed as they're doing lately.

Comment: I get the feeling [auto comments](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4978) wouldn't pass your 'ideal comment' test

Comment: @Peilonrayz Many of those comments were designed with those things in mind. While they might not be ideal, I consider them a lot better than the copy-paste of the close reason.

Comment: @Peilonrayz It's true that closing questions with a copy-paste of the close reason comment or without a comment at all is not a new problem. But in this chat room you are specifically aiming to close questions, when you do I hope you can do it in a good way. I've seen Mast has written in the chat room "Don't forget the comments".

Comment: A canned comment is better than no comment. Small steps. I was just getting glad people who previously left none, now might be inclined to tell OP what's going on (instead of leaving them wondering why it's attracting downvotes in silence) and hopefully the comment even has a link to our help center, which points out a great many valuable things for beginners and should be a mandatory read before posting.

Comment: @Mast How about we start to aim for at least 75% of the questions that you target having constructive comments? And 0% of questions where there is a new user asking a question and it gets closed without a comment? I don't have the manpower unfortunately, all I have is girl-bot-power. Posting good questions won't make the bad questions go away, sure, but it will still increase the quality of Code Review - which I believe is your goal as well.

Comment: @Mast A canned comment is better than no comment, sure, but I hope you read and understand the reasons for why I don't like the copy-paste of close reasons. The frequently posted comments-meta is a much better reference for canned comments.

Comment: So advocate using those in the mentioned room. I'm not against your canned comments. If you help with the good questions, I'll help with the clean-up of not-so-good questions and we'll both be doing what we're good at without having to openly criticize each other.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I basically agree with you that just repeating the close vote reasons in a comment isn't very useful, though we should new OPs giving a hint why their questions are downvoted and probably closed. I also agree with you that the room isn't intended to gather an _"angry mob"_ to chase offf new unexperienced users from the site. I was used to you give some canned comments along my close votes here, but was once noticed by the moderators I shouldn't do so and it's not considered constructive, So I stopped, and just casted my DV/CVs without any commenting.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Whilst I agree auto comments are better than nothing or a C&P of the close reason, I feel your answer is unfairly moving the goalposts. Don't get me wrong, moving them is _good_, but currently it looks like you're blaming the room for something that pre-existed it and it didn't aim to fix.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I believe it's a bit too early to judge about a progress. On the other hand I probably announced the room a bit too early here also. Though I wanted to address a broader audience to make them aware of. Just give us a little bit more time to improve everything.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Canned *constructive* comments are fine. Canned *unconstructive* comments are not that helpful and tend to gather flags. I'm sure the intentions behind the room are good, I am just expressing my concerns with the progress so far.

Comment: @Peilonrayz The goal of the room is to close questions rapidly, right? I'm not trying to blame the room for the problems that existed before, I want to highlight these problems and hope that the room improves in this regard. I believe that it's possible to close questions rapidly without being seen as an unfriendly community. Being strict with rules does not have to exclude being friendly. I don't want people who get their questions closed to leave and feel "What a nasty place, I will not go back there and I will tell everyone how horrible this experience was".

Comment: @Peilonrayz Instead if people get their questions closed I want them to feel "Okay, my question got closed, but now I understand the scope of this site better and know that I can come back if I have real working code that I want to improve"

Comment: @Simon Of course your contribution and observations are appreciated. Many newcomers seem to need to be pointed at _The Tour_ again in 1st place. The pattern I recognize with VLQ CR questions mostly comes with the new _New contributor_ warning most of the time (i.e. 1 or 101 rep users). Most of the other questions look OK. Note I am not voting regarding users, but content. The pattern is frequent though.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I understand your intent, and agree with it. We should try to make the site as welcoming as possible. It's only that your answer reads like the opposite of the following quote is true to me. "I'm not trying to blame the room for the problems that existed before".

Comment: Folks: small mod note here. Comments are not a chatroom. The sheer volume of comments suggests that we should discuss this answer somewhere that's more suited to discussion. Thanks!